# show Text when hover on a image with css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I'm trying to make a text Display on mouseover but i cant and i dont know how!
i tried many css codes but i failed.
And also i'm learning javaScript and i want to know how to do it with js
please see my code and help me slove my problem
Thanks and sorry if I'm making some rookie mistake

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap {
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.Time{
    border-radius: 1000px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    overflow: hidden
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
    

}
.Time:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"<li><div class="wrap"><img src="img/13.jpg" alt="EX" width="200" height="200" class="Time"></div></li></a>
```

Comment: what text do you want to display? There's no text in the HTML of your snippet.

Comment: Please, provide you HTML structure, for javascript way we need to see HTML

Comment: you want to show text over image or besides image?

Comment: ok, if you want to learn javascript then you may look into https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/ in examples or in some other javascript library / documentation or try the stackoverflow documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript#t=201705041255110465578

Comment: Example : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp

Comment: Maybe you an include a label in that div, and change the display style (block/none) in hover, or set the same color as the background

Comment: Obed Marquez Parlapiano : because i made alot tags idont know where to put the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution without javascript.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap {
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.Time{
    border-radius: 1000px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    overflow: hidden
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
    

}
.TimeTooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 90px;
}
.wrap:hover .Time {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    cursor:pointer;
}
.wrap:hover .TimeTooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><li><div class="wrap"><img src="img/13.jpg" alt="EX" width="200" height="200" class="Time"><span class="TimeTooltip">tooltip</span></div></li></a>
```

Comment: Thank you , It worked biut the text apear on the left top side of the image not on it . how to do that?

Comment: I modified the answer so that it appears more or less at the center of the image. To move it around you need to modify the "top" and "left" css properties.

Answer (score 0):

see below code snippet, if you want to show text besides image on hover.

```js
call();

function call() {
document.getElementsByClassName('Time')[0].addEventListener("mouseover", Show);
document.getElementsByClassName('Time')[0].addEventListener("mouseout", hide);
}
function hide() {
document.getElementsByClassName('imageText')[0].style.display = 'none';
}

function Show() {
 document.getElementsByClassName('imageText')[0].style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap {
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.Time{
    border-radius: 1000px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    overflow: hidden
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
    

}
.Time:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    cursor:pointer;
}

.imageText {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<a href="#"<li><div class="wrap"><img src="img/13.jpg" alt="EX" width="200" height="200" class="Time"></div></li></a>
<span class="imageText">text</span>
```